# What is "spatial feature encoding"? Can anyone give a concrete example?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

This [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=M64sDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR6&lpg=PR6&dq=spatial%20feature%20encoding,%20%60then%60%20random%20forest%20or%20support&source=bl&ots=gNQLzBU7dl&sig=ACfU3U1vS0HIaSF3Jqj8w36FmuWXPjnChQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBxqLRjbnjAhUNa80KHZ0vCcAQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=spatial%20feature%20encoding%2C%20%60then%60%20random%20forest%20or%20support&f=false) "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing" mentioned a term **spatial feature encoding**

> On the other hand, CNN models have been proved to have much higher
>   modeling capacity, compared to the previous image recognition
>   mainstream pipelines, e.g., HAAR, SIFT, HOG image features followed by
>   `spatial feature encoding`, then random forest or support vector
>   classifiers. Given millions of parameters to fit during model training
>   (much more than previous pipelines), CNN representation empowers and
>   enables computerized image recognition models, with a good possibility
>   to be able to handle more challenging imaging problems. The primary
>   risk is overfitting since model capacity is generally high in deep
>   learning but often very limited datasets are available (that are with
>   good quality of labels to facilitate supervised training). The core
>   topics of this book are represented by examples on how to address this
>   task-critical overfitting issue with deep learning model selection,
>   dataset resampling and balancing, and the proper quantitative
>   evaluation protocols or setups.

[image]

I googled a lot and didn't find explanation or definition of "spatial feature encoding".

What is "spatial feature encoding"? Can anyone give a concrete example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chatfield et al.](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2011/Chatfield11/chatfield11.pdf) provides a good survey of feature encoding methods.

From the introduction to that paper (emphasis my own):

> The typical object recognition pipeline is composed of the following three steps: (i) extraction of local image features (e.g., SIFT descriptors), **(ii) encoding of the local features in an image descriptor (e.g., a histogram of the quantized local features)**, and (iii) classification of the image descriptor (e.g., by a support vector machine).

I believe that "spatial feature encoding" refers to step (ii) in the typical pipeline. In this respect, I believe that the simplest possible example (and a standard one) would be the histogram encoding. If "spatial feature encoding" is meant to imply the preservation of some geometric information, than spatial binning is another technique to look at.